# finding the average of a column of subtable in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

I have this table (called Tweets) in access that looks like this

```
text   retweetCount    isRetweet
lal       1                 -1
lalal     2                  0
lal       0                  0
lalala    100               -1
```

and i am using

```
SELECT DISTINCT text,
FROM Tweets
WHERE isRetweet = -1;
```

in order to select the unique "texts" that have -1 at the column `isRetweet`. Lets call this subset of the original table, Table A.

How can i find the average of the `retweetCount` for the Table A ?

Comment: Hint:  `AVG()` calculates the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know enough SQL that the answer should be obvious:

```
SELECT AVG(retweetCount)
FROM Tweets
WHERE isRetweet = -1;
```

This is essentially how you asked the question.  If you don't understand SQL, you should spend a little time learning the language so you can use it effectively and efficiently.

If a given `text` value can appear multiple times with retweets, then you want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(retweetCount)
FROM (SELECT text, SUM(retweetCount) as retweetCount
      FROM Tweets
      WHERE isRetweet = -1
      GROUP BY text
     ) t;
```

The subquery calculates the total retweets for the text.  The outer then gets the average.

Comment: I am amateur in SQL to be honest. In your answer you don't filter between the unique text though, right ?

Comment: @quant . . . For the data you provided, none of the "text" values have more than on "isRetweet = -1".  Hence, the `DISTINCT` is unnecessary in your original query.  However, if this is possible, then you can sum the values at the text level before calculating the average.

Comment: I think i needed a simpler solution, and i ended up with `SELECT AVG(retweetCount)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT text, retweetCount
FROM Tweets
WHERE isRetweet = -1
     ) ;`

Comment: @quant . . . I don't really see how that is simpler.  `select distinct` and `group by` have very similar performance characteristics.